# PHP adding or subtracting elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query string.  For example:

```
?filters=1,2,3,4
```

It gets turned into an array:

```
$filters = explode(',', $_GET['filters']);
```

You could push a new value on

```
$filters = array_push($filters, $new->filter);
```

Then turn it into the query string

```
http_build_query($filters);
```

Or, remove a value

```
$filters = array_diff($filters, [$new->filter]);
```

Then turn it into the query string

```
http_build_query($filters);
```

I'm looking for an elegant solution to remove the item if it already exists or to add the item if it does not exist.  Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: George, that is the attempt?!  You would just simply test the array based on the functions I included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding you correctly "*I'm looking for an elegant solution to remove the item if it already exists or to add the item if it does not exist.*".  Also, not sure if it is elegant but may spark other ideas:

```
$filters = in_array($new->filter, $filters) ?
    array_diff($filters, [$new->filter]) :
    array_merge($filters, [$new->filter]);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's about as elegant as it gets, unless you want to use PHP's array notation "hack", e.g.

```
?filters[]=1&filters[]=2&filters[]=3&etc...
        ^^---
```

That'd save you the `explode()` stage and gives you the ability to treat `$_GET['filters']` as an array directly, but at the cost of an uglier/longer URL.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should write 2 functions, "remove" and "add", which would each loop through the array looking for the value in question. Then the remove function could remove it, and the add function could add it. The functions themselves would not be so elegant, but using them would be simple elsewhere in your code.